# AsyncImage is Rotating Portrait Images

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-asyncimage

I am downloading a JPG image from a remote server. If I use `AsyncImage`, portrait images taken from the phone's library are rotated 90 degrees. Landscape images taken from the phone's photo library are fine. Also, portrait and landscape photos taken from the phone's camera are fine. Looking at the image on a computer using the URL renders in the correct orientation. If, instead of using `AsyncImage` to display the image, I instead download it as Data and convert it to a `UJIImage`, it works fine. So this is only an issue when using `AsyncImage`. How can I prevent portrait images from rotating 90 degrees while still using `AsyncImage`?

```
        VStack {
            AsyncImage(url: imageURL, transaction: Transaction(animation: .spring())) { phase in
                switch phase {
                case .empty:
                    Color.purple.opacity(0.1)
                case .success(let image):
                    image
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                        .transition(.scale)
                case .failure(_):
                    Image(systemName: "exclamationmark.icloud")
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFit()
                @unknown default:
                    Image(systemName: "exclamationmark.icloud")
                }
            }
            .frame(width: 200, height: 250)
            .cornerRadius(10)
        }
```

Update: Although this doesn't specifically answer the question on `AsyncImage` I was able to get around this issue by performing a transform on the image before it is sent to the server. I know there are issues of orientation when sending as PNG; however, I was sending using `jpgData` from a `UIImage`. However, I applied this transform anyway before sending and it worked when receiving via `AsyncImage`. As a `UIImage` it would have been fine so some internal process within `AsyncImage` is handling it differently and thus this additional transform that is otherwise not required for `UIImage` or any other platform, is required in this instance.  Perhaps that is simply the answer, but I'll leave it as is given the question is about the behavior of `AsyncImage`.